# How to implement info about error when send message in MessageKit? SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

How to implement info about error when send message in MessageKit? 
I need show info when message not send. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to implement info about error when send message in **[MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit)** ?

To display information about a message with **[MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit)**, you need to use the `accessoryView` it's a view on the left or right of your message where you can add a button or image to show information. You can show information like that

[image]

In `MessagesDisplayDelegate` you can implement the method `configureAccessoryView`

Here is an example of how to do it:
In this example we simply add a button to the view

```
func configureAccessoryView(_ accessoryView: UIView,
                            for message: MessageType,
                            at indexPath: IndexPath,
                            in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) {
    // Remove old views from the previous use
    accessoryView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

    // Handle retry logic, you can display this button only if the upload fail as example 

    let button = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
    button.tintColor = .red
    accessoryView.addSubview(button)

    button.frame = accessoryView.bounds
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false // respond to accessoryView tap through `MessageCellDelegate`
    accessoryView.layer.cornerRadius = accessoryView.frame.height / 2
}
```

To detect a tap on the `accessoryView` you can implement `didTapAccessoryView` in the delegate `MessageCellDelegate`

```
func didTapAccessoryView(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
    guard let indexPath = messagesCollectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    // Handle tap here
    // As example here in my apps I display an actionSheet to cancel or retry
}
```

You can have another example [here](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/development/Example/Sources/View%20Controllers/AdvancedExampleViewController.swift)

Note: The request part of the retry is not part of **[MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit)** only the UI of your chat is the job of **[MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit)**

I hope my answer help you